# How can I make a JavaFX confirmation alert box wait till OK is pressed but perform other actions when other buttons are pressed

Tags: java, javafx, alert

I am writing a Java program in which at a certain point, a new directory has to be created. However, there should be an alert message whether the user wants to continue or not. The alert box has to contain the options to
1. Proceed
2. Discontinue
3. Show the targeted directory in Windows explorer.

I have already created an alert confirmation box (the method returns whether the program can proceed to move files to the targeted directory):

```
private static boolean createDir(Movie movie){
    String name = movie.name.getValue();
    File file = new File(Paths.get(target.getValue(),name).toString());
    if(!file.isDirectory()) {
        file.mkdir();
        return true;
    }
    else{
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
        alert.setTitle("Duplicate");
        alert.setHeaderText("This folder already exists");
        alert.setContentText("Do you want to continue (this program will overwrite any files with duplicate names)");

        ButtonType show = new ButtonType("Show in Explorer");
        alert.getButtonTypes().add(show);

        Optional<ButtonType> option = alert.showAndWait();

        if (option.get() == null) {
            return false;
        } else if (option.get() == ButtonType.OK) {
            return true;
        } else if (option.get() == ButtonType.CANCEL) {
            return false;
        } else if (option.get() == show) {
            try {
                Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File(file.getPath()));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return  false;
}
```

The problem is, that I want the alert box to stay on screen when the users clicks on "Show in Explorer". The user will look at the already existing folder and then click OK or cancel (or again show in Explorer).

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `option.get() == null` is always false.  If there is no response (because the user dismissed the dialog using the window decoration’s close button), `option.get()` throws an exception.  Use `!option.isPresent()` instead.

Comment: As soon as you want the dialog box to remain on the screen after selecting the option, you need to use EventFilter to stop the message and to run the logic you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
alert.setTitle("Duplicate");
alert.setHeaderText("This folder already exists");
alert.setContentText("Do you want to continue (this program will overwrite any files with duplicate names)");

ButtonType show = new ButtonType("Show in Explorer", ButtonBar.ButtonData.LEFT);
alert.getButtonTypes().add(show);

ButtonBar.setButtonUniformSize(alert.getDialogPane().lookupButton(show), false);
alert.getDialogPane().lookupButton(show).addEventFilter(ActionEvent.ACTION, event -> {
    try {
        Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File(new File(file.getPath())));
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    event.consume();
});

Optional<ButtonType> option = alert.showAndWait();
return ButtonType.OK.equals(option.get());
```

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm. The new EventFilter is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a regular button for "Show in Explorer", instead of making that one of the buttons that is created by default to correspond to a `ButtonType`. (The default behavior is to create a button that closes the dialog and sets the value of the dialog's result.)

If you want the convenience of an `Alert` and are OK with the slightly different UI this gives, you can do something like

```
    Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
    alert.setTitle("Duplicate");
    alert.setHeaderText("This folder already exists");
    alert.setContentText("Do you want to continue (this program will overwrite any files with duplicate names)");

    Button show = new Button("Show in Explorer");
    show.setOnAction(e -> {
        try {
            Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File(file.getPath()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
    alert.setGraphic(show);

    return alert.showAndWait().filter(ButtonType.OK::equals).isPresent();
```

If you want the button to appear in the button bar, you need to subclass `DialogPane` and override the `createButton` method to return a button that performs the action you want.

Here's a complete example using this approach:

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonType;
import javafx.scene.control.Dialog;
import javafx.scene.control.DialogPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class AlertWithRegularButton extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Button save = new Button("Save");
        save.setOnAction(e -> showDialog(primaryStage));

        StackPane root = new StackPane(save);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 250, 250);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void showDialog(Stage owner) {

        ButtonType showFileBrowserType = new ButtonType("Show in system file browser");

        DialogPane dialogPane = new DialogPane() {
            @Override
            protected Node createButton(ButtonType type) {
                if (type == showFileBrowserType) {
                    Button show = new Button(type.getText());
                    show.setOnAction(e -> {
                        try {
                            File home = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"));
                            Desktop.getDesktop().open(home);
                        } catch (IOException exc) {
                            exc.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    });
                    return show ;
                } else {
                    return super.createButton(type);
                }
            }
        };

        Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
        alert.setDialogPane(dialogPane);
        alert.setTitle("Duplicate");
        alert.setHeaderText("This folder already exists");
        alert.setContentText("Do you want to continue (this program will overwrite any files with duplicate names)");
        alert.getButtonTypes().addAll(showFileBrowserType, ButtonType.CANCEL, ButtonType.OK);
        alert.initOwner(owner);
        alert.showAndWait().filter(ButtonType.OK::equals).ifPresent(b -> {
            System.out.println("OK chosen");
        });

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have no doubt this will work and I understand what you're doing. But in my opinion mr mcwolf's answer is less comprehensive.